# Calculating the density of a Random variable which is dependent on another random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I came across the following problem in a book I was reading on continuous probability distributions:-

$Q.$ Let $Y$ be uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Find a function $\phi$ such that $\phi(Y )$ has the gamma density $\Gamma(\frac12,\frac12)$.

I know that the probability density represented by $\Gamma(\frac12,\frac12)$ is the following:-

$$\Gamma\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)=\begin{cases}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi x}}.e^{-\frac x2} &&&& x \ge 0 \\ 0 &&&& x <0\end{cases}$$

I don't have any idea what to do after this. I would also like to have insight on similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have any idea what to do after this.

So you want $f_{\phi(Y)}(x) = f_Y(\phi^{-1}(x))\cdot\lvert\frac{\mathrm d \phi^{-1}(x)}{\mathrm d x}\rvert$

and know $f_{\phi(Y)}(x) = \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi x}~e^{-2x}~\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;\infty)}$ and $f_Y(\phi^{-1}(x))=\mathbf 1_{\phi^{-1}(x)\in(0;1)}$ (assuming $\phi$ is bijective).

So what you do is substitute, rearrange and integrate.

$$\begin{align}
\newcommand{\erf}{\operatorname{erf}} 
\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi x}~e^{-2x} &= \lvert\frac{\mathrm d \phi^{-1}(x)}{\mathrm d x}\rvert
\\[1ex]
\phi^{-1}(x) &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^x \frac{e^{-s/2}}{\surd s}  \operatorname d s &&{x\in(0;\infty)}
\\[2ex]
y &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\phi(y)} s^{-1/2}e^{-s/2}\operatorname d s && {y\in(0;1)}
\\[1ex]
 &= \bbox[white,1ex,border:silver 1pt dotted]{\color{white}{\erf(\sqrt{\phi(y)/2~})}}
\end{align}$$

and you can take it from there.

Comment: it seems like the answer is incomplete...could you pls complete the answer?

Comment: You asked for what to do next.  This is what you do next.  You can complete it from there.

Comment: Ohk...cool down @Graham Kemp...and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that  $\phi$ is increasing, we can get:
$$t=P\left(Y<t\right)=P\left(\phi(Y)<\phi(t)\right)$$ and thus $\phi(t)=F_\Gamma^{-1}(t)$.

This is actually a well known result, which is used to generate a random sample from a given distribution. Look up [inverse transform sampling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).